# Trouble opening localhost with Node and mssql

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I'm using Node to connect to a Microsoft SQL Developer database. I've finally gotten my code to run without errors:

```
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


// Get request
app.get('/', function (req, res) {


// Config your database credential
const config = {
    server: "xxxx",
    driver:"xxxx",
    database: "xxxx",
    user: "xxxx",
    password: "xxxx",
    options:{
    trustServerCertificate: true,
}
};

// Connect to your database
new sql.ConnectionError(config,function(err){

    // Create Request object to perform
    // query operation
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // Query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from mydb',
        function (err, records) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // Send records as a response
            // to browser
            res.send(records);

        });
    });
});


var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is listening at port 5000...');
});
```

But, when I go to :

```
http://localhost:5000/
```

It doesn't load, it says the page cannot be reached. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: You don't access SQL Server via HTTP, so you can't expect http://localhost to do anything.

Comment: I'm confused.  This video does exactly that:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLcXfRH1YzE

Comment: ultimately, I'm trying to interact with a microsoft sql server db using javascript.. and I want to test things on localhost.. is there any direction you could point me in?  thanks!

Comment: another example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser/

Comment: Your last example shows your **site** being accessed at localhost:5000, **not** SQL Server. Have you accessed SQL Server via SSMS?

Comment: Is this the entirety of your code, or do you have additional code in which you use Express?  Express will act as your http server and handle the requests from your browser, likely on port 5000, so the url would be http://localhost:5000.  Express then hands off requests to msnodesql which is where the connection on port 1433 comes into play.

Comment: question updated.  Yes, I'm using Express..

Comment: That doesn't sound like an issue with SQL Server, rather with you NodeJS config.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong thing to try and connect to SQL Server.  You don't use `new sql.ConnectionError()`, you use `sql.connect()`.  This error is causing your app to crash so nothing is listening on port 5000.

```
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


// Get request
app.get('/', function (req, res) {


// Config your database credential
const config = {
    server: "xxxx",
    driver:"xxxx",
    database: "xxxx",
    user: "xxxx",
    password: "xxxx",
    options:{
    trustServerCertificate: true,
}
};

// Connect to your database
sql.connect(config,function(err){

    // Create Request object to perform
    // query operation
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // Query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from mydb',
        function (err, records) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // Send records as a response
            // to browser
            res.send(records);

        });
    });
});


var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is listening at port 5000...');
});
```

Run that (after having applied proper database connection configuration values) and then you should be able to open your browser and connect to http://localhost:5000